# Python Executable including multiple libraries

Tags: pyinstaller, exe, openpyxl

I am relatively new to Python and have developed an application for myself that I would like to make an executable. It uses multiple external libraries such as Pyqt5, sqlite3, and openpyxl.  I am using pyinstaller to create the .exe - the installer fails with a message "nomodulefound xml.parser.expat" i've tried a few ways to include it in my package but to no avail.

here is a replicable py example:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
import openpyxl  # xl libraries
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\jmstr\OneDrive\Documents\finproxlc.xlsx')
myint = Decimal("27")
print("hello")
```

any ideas?

Here is my pyinstaller cmd: pyinstaller C:\Users\usr1\IdeaProjects\GUIProjects\finpro.py -p C:\Users\usr1\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl --hidden-import openpyxl --additional-hooks-dir C:\Users\usr1\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl --collect-all xml.parsers.expat

Output of the pyinstall:

['C:\Users\usr1\IdeaProjects\GUIProjects', 'C:\Users\usr1\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl'] Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in *run_module_as_main return *run_code(code, main_globals, None, File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "C:\Users\usr1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in  File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py", line 194, in *console_script_run run() File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py", line 180, in run run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args)) File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py", line 61, in run_build PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs) File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 977, in main build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build) File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 899, in build exec(code, spec_namespace) File "C:\Users\usr1\finpro.spec", line 14, in  a = Analysis( File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 379, in **init** self.hookspath += discover_hook_directories() File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated_parent.py", line 404, in wrapped return call(function, *args, **kwargs) File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated_parent.py", line 373, in call return isolated.call(function, *args, **kwargs) File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated_parent.py", line 311, in call raise RuntimeError(f"Child process call to {function.**name**}() failed with:\n" + output) RuntimeError: Child process call to discover_hook_directories() failed with: File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated_child.py", line 63, in run_next_command output = function(*args, **kwargs) File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 107, in discover_hook_directories import pkg_resources File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_*init*_.py", line 35, in  import plistlib File "c:\users\usr1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\plistlib.py", line 61, in  from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xml.parsers'

Comment: createa  a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the installion of openpyxl was specific to my IDE (intelliJ) and i could not figure out how to change the spec file to get it to pick up but running this command resolved the issue:

```
python -m pip install openpyxl
```